# Log cat reading lots of data when i connect my mobile to to IDE

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

this question is not related to programming but it is now eating up my head. problem is that i am testing my app on my android mobile by enabling usb debug mode on. Initially it was fine and i used to see on my logcat screen only the messages what i print through my own app but now unnecessary messages are popping up on Log cat and those are like hundreds in every minute. i believe i have enabled any option by mistake which causing other apps installed in my mobile filling up my logcat screen of IDE. problem has grown so much that it has become almost impossible to find the log cats of my own app in the logcat.... i do not see any option checked in the developer{} screen except "enable usb debut mode" . can anyone suggest me any solution so that i see only my apps logs on log cat screen.... thanks !

Comment: You probably removed the filter that pertains to your package on the IDE

Comment: Which IDE are you using ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Android Studio (and I think even on Eclipse is the same), you should set your LogCat filter to your app, like the img below:

[image: Your logcat tab]

The img url: https://i.stack.imgur.com/o7vik.png

By selecting your app, you will only see the logs related to your app !

Comment: Thanks Leo but image is missing ;)

Comment: What you mean, you can't see it ?

Comment: yeah i couldn't see it not even now :D... but anyway i found the image and applied the filter for my app package. can i add multiple projects sepearate by "," in "filter by application" ?